# JavaScript images showing "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am testing out images on my code. It seems to work, but it is saying "undefined" next to the image, what would this problem be with this? Thanks.

Here is my code below:

```
function greater(){
    document.write(`Amazing minimum wage you got there! That's a lot of freddos you can buy! I hope you are not lying about this. <br>`);
    const success = document.createElement("img");
    success.src = "https://brightspace.uhi.ac.uk/content/enforced/199637-DEVINGL4W46/csfiles/home_dir/index.jfif?_&d2lSessionVal=DeyxkZTbYZqljp2vvW5DPQJ9n&ou=199637";
    document.body.appendChild(success);
}


document.write(greater())
```

Comment: You are writing the return value of `greater()` which doesn't return anything and so is `undefined`. Just call `greater()` without wrapping it in `document.write()`.

Comment: Oh I see, seems to work fine now, thanks!